# Why I'm getting unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' for my cron job?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here's my Cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * aide --check | echo  "Start timestamp: `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" > /var/log/aide/aide2.log
```

Comment: That pipe is wrong, btw.

Comment: No, it's not wrong.. I found a solution with pipe :)

Comment: `echo` doesn't use stdin, so it can't be right

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `%` sign is treated specially in crontab. Those, if needed literally have to be escaped with `\` Here is a quote from manpage:

> The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to
>   be run.  The entire command portion of the line, **up to a newline or %
>   character**, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell
>          specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\),
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first
>          % will be sent to the command as standard input. There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the
>   shell's trailing "\".

However, as wRAR pointed, that pipe makes no sense. You probably wanted `||` there instead of `|`.